# Getting meta information from many-to-many table in Prisma

Tags: graphql, apollo, prisma

I have this table structure

[image]

Notice the `item_level` key

What I need to accomplish is to have the same item, attached to many players but each player can level up the item independently.

This is the simplest structure I could think of and in sql terms it's easy to join the tables, select the fields and show these connections.

My issue is, I'm using Apollo graphql and **Prisma** ORM (v ^**2.18.0**) and even though I can get the items of each player and vice-versa, I cannot figure out how to include that extra field.

prisma.schema

```
model Player {
    id      Int              @id @default(id())
    items   ItemToPlayer[]
}

model Item {
    id      Int              @id @default(id())
    players ItemToPlayer[]
}

model ItemToPlayer {
    player      Player  @relation(fields: [playerId], references: [id])
    playerId    Int
    item        Item    @relation(fields: [itemId], references: [id])
    itemId      Int
    itemLevel   Int     @default(0)

    @@id([playerId, itemId])
}
```

typeDefs

```
const typeDefs = gql`
    type Player {
        id: ID!
        items: [Item]
    }

    type Item {
        id: ID!
        players: [Player]
    }

    type ItemToPlayer {
        playerId: Int!
        itemId: Int!
        itemLevel: Int!
    }
`;
```

resolvers

```
const resolvers = {
    Player: {
        items: (parent, args, context, info) => {
            return context.db.item.findMany({
                where: {
                    players: {
                        some: {
                            playerId: parent.id
                        }
                    }
                },
                include: {
                    players: true
                }
            });
        },
    },

    Item: {
        players: (parent, args, context, info) => {
            return context.db.player.findMany({
                where: {
                    items: {
                        some: {
                            itemId: parent.id
                        }
                    }
                },
                include: {
                    items: true
                }
            });
        },
    },

    Query: { /* ... */ },

    Mutation: {  /* ... */ },
};
```

This is the result I would like to get when querying players including their items

```
{
    "data": {
        "players": [
            {
                "id": 1
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "itemLevel": 2 // <--- This is missing 
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "itemLevel": 3
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "itemLevel": 0 // same item (id: 1) has different level per player
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

In the [documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations#one-to-many-relations) it describes this as an *explicit many-to-many* relation and it mentions

> Note that the same rules as for 1-n-relations apply (because Post↔
> CategoriesOnPosts and Category ↔ CategoriesOnPosts are both in fact
> 1-n-relations), which means one side of the relation needs to be
> annotated with the @relation attribute.

but it provides no example.

Looking further into the `1-n-relations` and the `@relation`, the only examples I found are for foreign keys.

Searching around the Internet I found other people asking the same question about different frameworks and ORMs but found nothing for Prisma. (*unless I missed it*)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing your typedefs to:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
    type Player {
        id: ID!
        items: [ItemToPlayer]
    }

    type Item {
        id: ID!
        players: [ItemToPlayer]
    }

    type ItemToPlayer {
        playerId: Int!
        itemId: Int!
        itemLevel: Int!
        player: Player!
        item: Item!
    }
`;
```

And then your `players` resolver in the `Item` would look like:

```
prisma.player.findMany({
    where: {
      items: {
        some: {
          itemId: parent.id,
        },
      },
    },
    include: {
      items: { include: { item: true } },
    },
})
```

Comment: Changing the typeDefs to `ItemToPlayer` instead of `Item` helped as I can query the itemToPlayer in db and then query the Item in the result. The nested `include`  gave me an error. I managed to do it without nesting include. I do have to modify the query itself though.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the metadata by changing `Item` to `ItemToPlayer` as @Ryan suggested in his answer and changing my query and the resolver.

new `Item` resolver

```
Item: {
    players: (parent, args, context, info) => {
        return context.db.itemToPlayer.findMany({
            where: {
                itemId: parent.id
            },
            include: {
                item: true
            }
        });
    },
},
```

I am now querying the `ItemsToPlayers` table and getting back an `ItemToPlayer` type which I can then query the `Item` from

```
CORRECT
query {
  players {
    id
    items {
      id
      itemLevel
      item {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}

WRONG
query {
  players {
    id
    items {
      id
      itemLevel <--- This is wrong as itemLevel
                                    does not exist in Item
    }
  }
}
```

Result

```
{
    "data": {
        "players": [
            {
                "id": 1
                "items": [
                    {
                        "itemLevel": 2
                        "item": {
                             "id": 1,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "itemLevel": 0
                        "item": {
                             "id": 1,
                        }
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
}
```